# How to get element names from an xml document in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a xml file like:

```
<config>
   <email  Host="201.0.0.0" From="mail@mail.com" Pass="xxx" Name="xxx"/>
   <gir    g1="Traditional" g2="mid Techn" g3="High Tech"/>
   <costs>
     <Pre-Incube    inscr="7000.00"  add="300.00"/>
     <Normal        inscr="1600.00"  inc="7000.00" add="500.00"/>
     <Urgent        inscr="1600.00"  inc="5000.00" add="500.00"/>
     <Estance       inscr="1600.00"  men="2500.00"/> 
     <Post          inscr="1600.00"  men="1500.00"/> 
   </costs>
</config>
```

To get the attributes for the element "gir" I do

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(path)
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement         
Dim nodeGir As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/config/gir")
cboGir.Items.Add(nodeGir.Attributes.ItemOf("g1").InnerText)
cboGir.Items.Add(nodeGir.Attributes.ItemOf("g2").InnerText)
cboGir.Items.Add(nodeGir.Attributes.ItemOf("g3").InnerText)
```

But how do I get the *names* of the child elements under "costs":

```
Pre-Incube, Normal, Urgent, Estance, Post
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Dim costs As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/config/costs")

Dim i As Integer 
For i = 0 To costs.ChildNodes.Count - 1
    cboGir.Items.Add(costs.ChildNodes[i].Name)
Next i
```

Or probably easier (from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx)):

```
Dim costs As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/config/costs/*")
For Each book In costs      
    cboGir.Items.Add(book.Name)
Next
```

[Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.name.aspx) is a property on [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxz4hfh3.aspx) - the docs are your friend.

Comment: I have tried both   

  `Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/config/costs")
                For Each instance As XmlNode In node.ChildNodes
                    cboGir.Items.Add(instance.InnerText)
                Next`  
And 
    
`            Dim costs As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/config/costs")
                For Each book In costs
                    Console.WriteLine(book.InnerText)
                Next `

but the combobox I am trying to populate is empty after doing this

Comment: Ampreciate your help, but I am looking for the elements of "costs" not the atts of that element, I have tried your code but I still get nothing in a combo box

Comment: I see, sorry, the *names* of the elements. That's unusual, usually it's the content you're interested in. Updated again.

Answer (score 2):

To get the names of all the elements that are children of costs, you can do this:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/config/costs/*")
    cboGir.Items.Add(node.Name)
Next
```